# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` of type `string` supplied to `ForwardRef(FormControl)`, expected `boolean`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a material-ui Textfield component in my ReactJS project.

When I run my code, the warning I got in the console is:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` of type `string` supplied to `ForwardRef(FormControl)`, expected `boolean`.
```

My component code is below.
`<Field label="First Name*" name="firstName" component={InputField} type="text" placeholder="First Name" className="form-control" />`
This code works totally fine but the problem is that it gives a warning message in the console.

**Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` of type `string` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextField)`, expected `boolean`.**

Is there any ES6 or any other solution to this?

Comment: try to pass error={true}

Answer (score 2):

This warning comes when you are passing a string value to the boolean property in mui. Like "error", when you give it true it will show an error else will be normal. And if you doing like this error={"some state"} give this a default boolean value otherwise this warning will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, I solved changing the default value for a non-empty string

Answer (score 0):

you can set the value to null if the `not found` or `undefined`